# Xcode 4, how to send entire project/workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode4, derived

I have a project/workspace that I want to zip up and send to someone so they can compile it on their machine. It's an iOS app.

One thing I am noticing is when I zip the project directory it turns out to be over 1gb. I deleted the Derived Data folder in the project directory.

However, for some reason it's picking up derived data from ~/Librar/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and putting it into the zip file.

There isn't, as far as I can tell, multiple projects.

What is the best approach to send someone the project with out it being huge?

Is there a way to turn off derived data?

Comment: Something is wrong if your project is 1GB.

Comment: I'd recommend using git or another version control system and control only project-related files.  Mask out data you don't want to send with the ignore facilities relevant to the particular vcs.

Comment: James - yes that was obvious when the file was so huge. I seems to have come down to the derived data. Art - eventually yes but I need a solution now and it seems silly you HAVE to use git instead of simply zipping and sending a file. There really no way around this? Really? :-(

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "*.xcodeproj" and click on "Show package contents". Try to send the ".xcworkspace" included in it. Hope This is what you are expecting :) .

Comment: Eventually we will be setting up git but for now just want to zip up the file and send it over. Seems kinda silly that you HAVE to use git to share a project. Been doing zipping and sending projects for a long time but now with Xcode 4 you can't seem to. There really is no way around this?